# how to pronounce 'Uriel'?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I have a student whose name is 'Uriel' and I'm just wondering how I should pronounce it!

Comment: Because name pronunciations can be unique, I'd ask her just to be sure.

Comment: It is commonly pronounced _you riel_.

Comment: Probably varies ... UK, US, NZ, etc...

Comment: This is a question about the pronunciation of a person's name. This is not really a question about the English language at all.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'd assumed Finn would ask *him* (Uriel is one of the archangels along with Michael, Gabriel and Raphael).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the link can be helpful.

http://www.forvo.com/word/uriel/

Answer (score 1):

Asking her would certainly be the best strategy.  She might not pronounce it according to a dictionary.

Almost no-one takes offense at being asked their name - usually, quite the opposite.